# Problem with generics used as object keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using a variable with a generic as an object key and it doesn't seem to work. Here i have a very simple example where I have two objects (I'm using declare to tell TS there's something there without having to create the object), which both share some of the same keys, but they both also have keys the other doesn't. Then I have a function with a generic which is type that must be a key of both the objects. Then I use the key to assign the value of one object to another, but TypeScript doesn't like it, specifically the object that is being assigned to. But I don't know why, because the key has to be a key of both objects and because I'm using a generic, it should know it will be okay, since they are assignable to each other.

It works if:

- If the object being assigned to has no keys that the other object doesn't.
- All the keys that they share together have the same type, as in they share the keys "b", "c", "d" and the values for those keys are all, for example, number.
- When it's not a generic, as demonstrated at the bottom.

So here's an example:

```js
// these don't matter, it only matters they aren't assignable to each other (strictNullCheck: true, null is not assignable to undefined)
type A = number
type B = string
type C = boolean
type D = null
type E = undefined

type Test1 = {
    a: A
    b: B
    c: C
    d: D
}
declare const test1: Test1

type Test2 = {
    b: B
    c: C
    d: D
    e: E
}
declare const test2: Test2

function testFn<T extends keyof Test1 & keyof Test2>(t: T) {
    test1[t] = test2[t]
//  ^^^^^^^^
    // Type 'Test2[T]' is not assignable to type 'Test1[T]'.
    // Property 'a' is missing in type 'Test2' but required in type 'Test1'. ts(2322)
}

const key = 'b'
test1[key] = test2[key] // works fine with b, c, d
```

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

The problem with the testFn function is that it is not type-safe. The T type parameter is constrained to be a key of both Test1 and Test2, but Test2 does not have a property a.
This means that the line test1[t] = test2[t] will fail to compile with the error message **Type 'Test2[T]' is not assignable to type 'Test1[T]'. Property 'a' is missing in type 'Test2' but required in type 'Test1'**

### To fix this problem :

1. Change the type parameter T to be keyof Test2. This will allow the function to be used with any property of Test2, but it will no longer be type-safe for Test1.
2. Add a type guard to the function to check if the t parameter is a key of Test1. If it is, then the function can safely assign test2[t] to test1[t].
3. To assign a value to a property that may not exist in the type, you can use the ? operator. This operator will tell TypeScript that the property is optional.

### Solution

```
 // type guard:

function testFn<T extends keyof Test1 & keyof Test2>(t: T): void {
          if (t in Test1) {
            test1[t] = test2[t];
          }
        }



 //using as :
     function testFn<T extends keyof Test2>(t: T): void {
          test1[t] = test2[t] as Test1[T] | undefined;
        }
```

### Output

```
testFn('b'); // works fine
testFn('c'); // works fine
testFn('d'); // works fine
testFn('a'); // works fine, but the value of `test1.a` will be `undefined`
```

Comment: `"a"` is not in `keyof Test1 & keyof Test2` so I'm not sure why you're mentioning it or why you think the function isn't safe.  If you use the orig code you are not allowed to call `testFn('a')`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue described at [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693).

TypeScript won't let you assign an indexed access to another indexed access like `o1[k1] = o2[k2]`, even if the objects and the keys are of the same type.  That's because the type alone isn't enough to guarantee safety; if the keys are of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `"b" | "c" | "d"` then you could accidentally have `k1` be `"b"` and `k2` be `"c"`.  This type safety strengthening was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) and although it does help prevent mistakes, it also unfortunately prevents a lot of perfectly safe assignments.  Specifically, when you have `o1[k] = o2[k]` where the key on both sides of the assignment isn't just the same *type*, but actually the same *value*, then it should be safe.  But TypeScript doesn't currently track the identity of the keys, just their types.

Currently the only permitted approach is to use generic keys (you're already doing this) and objects of the same type (and this part is where it's breaking for you), as described in [this comment in ms/TS#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559).  So you can fix your error if you can express at least one of the objects as having a type compatible with the other.  For example:

```
function testFn<T extends keyof Test1 & keyof Test2>(t: T) {
  const t1: Omit<Test1, "a"> = test1
  t1[t] = test2[t]
}
```

This is a safe widening of `test1` from `Test1` to `Omit<Test1, "a">` using [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys), and we're using a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) instead of a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) so that the compiler would warn us if it were unsafe.  And then `t1[t] = test2[t]` works because it sees `test2` as also being of type `Omit<Test1, "a">`.

It would be great if this happened automatically, but it doesn't.  And it would also be great if the identity of `t` mattered to the compiler, but it doesn't.  Even the workaround isn't necessarily safe since you can go through the same exercise with `k1` and `k2` where both are generic.  So in all this is a lot of hoop jumping to enable something that most people expect to work without it.  But that's currently the state of things.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsFMGdtAEwPYDsDk5QFsCG5xoAnAGlAEss0AbATx30KNghntyOgy11lnIDmqXACNqCcMlDRcAY0ihkUYqAAUscEXKzwAOQCu1agGEYsgNYAuCEX3QyqQ9QotUS0L35DR4iFP2oiNAAZuSo0IgAlACwAFDgtAAOCACCoAC8oI7YIsRxCcmgAEIZoBpaqAL5SQjGpSLIyOK4qNWFACKljkZtCACipQFBoeGIcb2gACpw4ACMpQDecaAe1inLoCLWRRuy1sYbiNbtcQC+cUGy1BwIsmgaEDOz1tMas+PxNVMzAEyLG1tirt9odjhtoNY+mcLtArjdQHdUA9CBofi9fh9ggEdOQ0I8NAAxVAAHkm0gAHoRAixzNBaMhgt83qAAGSgWn0xmvcA-AB8qnAL0ioCWsRWiORz1AAHlsJRSU8yAAiXBK3mlFFzDZzADa4AAuhrfnr9dDYkA)